# WinUI3-MVVM: Setting UI control focus from ViewModel

Tags: windows, winui-3

What is a good practice of setting control focus in MVVM architecture. I tried FocusBehavior but it didn't work. What's the best solution ?

## FocusBehavior.cs

```
public class FocusBehavior
{
    public static void SetIsFocused(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetIsFocused(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsFocused",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(FocusBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    var uiElement = d as UIElement;
                    if (uiElement != null)
                    {
                        uiElement.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
                    }
                }
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: What's the relation betweeen this piece of code that does nothing on it own but setting focus on an element and the "good practise of focus in MVVM"? You should clarify. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, the background is like this. I bind the Command in the ViewModel to verify the form. When the verification fails, I need to set the focus of the TextBox from the ViewModel. If the verification form is in the code behind, set txtUser.Focus(FocusState. Pointer), but I think this breaks the MVVM principle

Answer (score 1):

As it's mentioned in the comments, you should clarify a bit more you issue.
I also want to mention that "Focus" is a UI feature. ViewModels shouldn't be worried if the control has focus or not. If possible, try to change the focus in the code behind. But there might be cases where you need to change the focus depending on the ViewModel.

In order to make your code work, your need to handle focus events:

```cs
public class FocusBehavior
{
    public static void SetIsFocused(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsFocused(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsFocused",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(FocusBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is UIElement uiElement &&
            e.NewValue is bool newValue)
        {
            if (newValue is true)
            {
                uiElement.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
                uiElement.LostFocus += UiElement_LostFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                uiElement.GotFocus += UiElement_GotFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void UiElement_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is UIElement uiElement)
        {
            uiElement.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, false);
            uiElement.LostFocus -= UiElement_LostFocus;
        }
    }

    private static void UiElement_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is UIElement uiElement)
        {
            uiElement.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, true);
            uiElement.GotFocus -= UiElement_GotFocus;
        }
    }
}
```